# Gazebo on Ubuntu 12.10 installation problem

Tags: installation, gazebo-1.4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[link text](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/screenshotfrom201303091.png/)

I got this when I try to install Gazebo manually, using commands from README file.
Could anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1705/gazebo-on-ubuntu-12.10-installation-problem/) by [MoonWalker](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/248/moonwalker/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Please try the instruction located here: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/install

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0